# Is there any open source CMS user management and administration system based on PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, content-management-system, administration, content-management

I've try many CMS flavors like MODx, Drupal, Joomla for the admin Panel but they can't seem to manage my existing data, like the users.

I'm planing on building some kind of control panel for my site, similar to the one that is used for managing users and other non-content related items in a CMS. I was wondering if there is something out there which I can start working with instead of starting from scratch.

**UPDATE:**
To do simple tasks like:

- Managing my users
- Managing my content( the site is an image sharing site, so in this case images)

I was looking more into a graphical interface more then a system as i have lots of costume content and data like the users.

Comment: Just to get this straight: do you mean "control panel" == "CMS"? In that case, disregard my answer. There are a gazillion PHP-based CMS's around.

Comment: You really should change your question to clear up the fact that you need a Content Management System, NOT a control panel.

Comment: i changed it, i think that an "admin panel" is what im looking for. You know how CMS have their Admin panel. I'm just looking for an admin panel LIKE a CMS has, not a whole CMS. hope is clearer.

Comment: I helped your changes a bit further, hope you don't mind, hope it's clearer now ;) (hmm, can't seem to get the title right, if anybody has better ideas)

Comment: If you're using your own custom CMS, then you have to make your own admin panel, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the question has cleared up a bit, here's a [starter's manual for a PHP CMS](http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/) which takes you by the hand, but from scratch. It starts out with managing users, which seems to be what you're after.

Since you're talking of hosting a lot of pictures, you may want to look up the more than excellent [Gallery 2 from Menalto](http://gallery.menalto.com/), which is an open source picture management system, but goes much further than just that. It's written in PHP and very actively maintained.

Finally, a [list of open source CMS's](http://www.scriptol.com/cms/list.php), of which most of them are written in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your patients, i feel like im heading in the right direction now.

Answer (score 1):

You start out with CMS's, then you switch to control panels, maybe I misunderstand, but let me try anyway. Maybe you mean to find a control panel that can control your home-build CMS? Most current control panels support PHP and may well support any CMS (like [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) or [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/eu/products/plesk/) or [the likes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels)).

Building an administration control panel is a huge undertaking. Most of the time, a control panel consists of a front end (which could be build in PHP) and a backend that serves as a layer between the frontend and the underlying operating system. PHP might not be the handiest choice on all OS's.

**EDIT:**
If you do not need to support Windows, the "huge undertaking" might be quite less. Here are some PHP-based control panels: [Baifox](http://www.baifox.org/) (open source), [InterWorx](http://www.interworx.com/) (proprietory), [ISPConfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/) (open source), [SysCP](http://www.syscp.org/) (open source), [ispCP](http://isp-control.net/) (backend Perl, open source).

Comment: What? You did see the "for my site" in his question, didn't you? Why would he have to "need to interface a lot with the OS and its programs"?

Comment: I thought he wrote "Admin Control Panel". But I may have misunderstood.

Comment: im not builid a webhosting site

Comment: I'm voting this up because it's a good answer to the question that was asked, even though it wasn't what was intended.